# Python: Using Tables for Specific Info

Tags: python, datatables

So, I have a large .txt file with a bunch of data that I have linked for reference. Go to the link, click on the "Data Release" tab on the left, and enter the "Spectroscopic source catalogues, finally, download "All NGP strip sources" which is a compressed file. Once you decompress, you can open it as a txt file. It is a VERY large table detailing observations of thousands of cosmological objects.

First, I needed to get this table into Python, which I did using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.loadtxt('parent.ngp.txt', skiprows=1)
```

Now, the data in the text file has many columns. If you look at column 8, it is titled "qual." Let's say I want to keep every row of the table except those in which the value of qual is equal to or less than 3.

So I want to delete all rows where qual is equal to or less than 3 and now have that be an updated table.

How can I approach this? Is there any method that doesn't require many packages such as pandas?

Thank you, Q

[txt file link from website](http://www.2dfgrs.net/)

Comment: Instead of `VERY large table detailing observations of thousands of cosmological objects` why don't you make a minimal example that can demonstrate the issue? It sounds like you just want `np.where()` or regular numpy indexing with an inequality.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have posted an updated question based on your advice. You can see it if you go to my profile and I would love your answer on it!